# How can I get Wordpress to ask for a custom image width on every image I upload?

Tags: php, image, wordpress, image-processing

I'm designing a blog for someone who wants to use a custom size for every single image.

The easiest way would be to just have a field on the image uploader next to where it asks 'medium, large' etc. saying "Width:***_***". Then the image will be scaled to be that width and embedded in the post at that size.

I can see there would be lots of ways to hack this in, or write a plug in to do it - but is there an easy way to do this, or an existing plug in?

Thanks!
Cole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found to this was the plugin by Walter Vos, http://www.waltervos.com/wordpress-plugins/additional-image-sizes/ which allows you to specify new image sizes globally. It's well written and did just what we needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in, writting a post/page, 
once they click to upload a picture, if they are on the visual editor.
then just click on the image and select the "Edit Image" button that pops up, 
the dialog window opens with 2 tabs at the top, click on "Advance settings" tab
and they can select the width & height from there?

Comment: That's one option, but unfortunately it only changes the width/height in the CSS - I'm looking to get WP to generate and display a real thumbnail.